# Django - Form element's default value error

Tags: django, django-forms

there are two links in one page[admin page]. both goes to same form page[ Add Post ]. in admin page ; you can click to 'new post' link or you can type your title in a textbox which is connected to same page[Add Post]. in that page ; i have a form which have a checkbox field.

```
isdraft = forms.BooleanField(required=False,initial=True)
```

as you can see ; i set the field's default value True. if i click the 'new post' at admin page ; to come that form page ; it works great. checkbox comes to me as True. but if i use other way  [ typing title in textbox ] checkbox comes to me as False. i couldn't figure that out.

**edit** : i think the question is complicated. not clear. if any additional data needed ; i can add it.

**edit** :

admin.html :

```
<h1>Posts<a href="{% url add_post %}" class="button">New Post</a></h1> #this works!

    <form action="{% url add_post %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.title }} <!-- this is textbox -->
        {{ form.isdraft.as_hidden }} <!-- when i add this line form works correctly. but i get 'please fill all fields' warning when redirected to add_post page. -->
    </form>
```

**edit2** :
add_post view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def add_post(request):

    template_name = 'add.html'
    owner = request.user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            titleform = form.cleaned_data['title']
            bodyform = form.cleaned_data['body']
            checkform = form.cleaned_data['isdraft']

            n = Post(title=titleform, body=bodyform, isdraft=checkform, owner=owner)
            n.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 
                'New post created successfully!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/post/add/')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, 
                'Please fill in all fields!')
    else:
        form = addForm()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'form': form, 'owner':owner,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
```

admin view :

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')

def admin_view(request):
    if request.session.get('loggedin') == "djangoo":
        form = newDraft() # textbox in admin page
        return render_to_response('admin.html', {'form':form },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

addForm :

```
class addForm(forms.Form):

    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Title here',}))
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'placeholder':'Write post here','rows':'25','cols':'90',}))
    isdraft = forms.BooleanField(required=False,initial=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initial` only works when the form is [unbound](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms).

When you click the new post link, you are doing a get request on the page, so the form is unbound and the `initial` value is used.

When you enter a title and submit, I assume you are doing a post request on the page. Therefore the form is bound, and the `initial` value will not be used.

I'm afraid I don't understand the question completely, and you haven't show much code, so I can't suggest any work arounds for you. Hope you get it working.

### Update following edits to your question

When the data comes from the `add_post` view, don't create a bound form, because then the data will be validated and you'll get the error messages.

Instead, fetch the `title` from the post data, and use that to create an `initial` dictionary to instantiate your `addForm` with.

You need a way to tell whether the post request came from the admin or add post view. You could do this by adding another hidden field to the `addForm`.

```
action = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, initial="addform")
```

Then change your `add_post` view to something like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'addform':
        form = addForm(initial={'title': request.POST.get('title'), 'isdraft': True})
    else:
        # your existing code for handling a request post
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what i mean. so what can i do to make checkbox come as True? can you define a how-to way? thank you

Comment: or may be there is way to post that textbox to form page without post request ? what i want is ; when i type title into textbox; i want to see form page as 'just' title field bounded(filled).

Comment: You can't bind a subset of a form's fields. The entire form is either bound or unbound. Try adding a boolean field `isdraft` where the user types the title. If you get that to work, the second step is to use a hidden widget and make it default to true. I can't help any more unless you update the question to explain how typing the title then submitting works, ideally including some code.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but it's still not enough information. We need to see the view (views?) that are creating the forms as well.

Comment: i added add_post view. this is related to my add_post form page.

Comment: What about the view that renders the `admin.html` template?

Comment: We're getting there, slowly. What does the `addForm` look like? Is `initial=True` for the `isdraft` field?

Comment: Your question has now evolved from 'how do I get `initial=True` to work' to 'how do I prevent the form being validated and showing error messages'. I've updated my answer with a suggestion.